# Make an image responsive with 70% height of parent but autmoatic width

Tags: angularjs, layout, angular-material

in angular.js I am trying to set a Logo which should have70% of the height of its parent and a automatic width that it does not get cropped.

```
<md-content id="WelcomeView" ng-controller="WelcomeController" layout="column" flex>
    <md-content id="LogoElement" layout="row" flex="60" layout-align="center end">
        <img layout="row" src="styles/assets/dml-logo.png" ng-style="view.logo"/>
    </md-content>
    <md-content layout="row" flex layout-align="center start">
        <md-content layout="column" flex>
            <md-content layout="row" flex layout-align="center center"><H1>Arbeitsprobe</H1></md-content>
            <md-content layout="row" flex layout-align="center center"><H2>by Dirk Moll</H2></md-content>
            <md-content layout="row" flex layout-align="center center"><H3>in 2016</H3></md-content>
        </md-content>
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```

Any hint for me?

cu n00n

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/kXwgAA)

The image does stretch though if the height is always 70%.

Markup

```
<div id="parent">
  <div layout-fill layout="column">
    <div id="logo" flex="70">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

#logo {
  background-image: url("http://m.hiapphere.com/data/icon/201409/HiAppHere_com_kov.theme.lumos.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```